# Clear NeoVim Terminal window

Tags: neovim

I am using NeoVim terminal with picocom.  Every so ofter, I would like to clear the terminal buffer/screen inside the NeoVim terminal without exiting picocom, is there a short cut that clears the NeoVIM terminal buffer?

Comment: That does require exiting `picocom`, which is what I am trying to get around.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, looking for `:redraw!` ? I never used picocom, but i'm confident that `:redraw!` is present in neovim. (the `!` at the end of `:redraw!` is to force the clearing of the screen before redrawing.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want isn't possible.  `picocom` would need to clear the screen, but it's not a curses program so it can't.  If you want to declutter the screen so you can stay focused on new output, you can "clear" what's on the screen by modifying the colors of what's displayed in the terminal window.

```
function! s:fake_clearterm() abort
  let top = line('w0') - 1
  let bottom = min([line('$'), line('w$')]) + 1
  silent! call matchdelete(1234)
  call matchadd('FakeClearTerm', '\%>'.top.'l\_.*\%<'.bottom.'l', 0, 1234)
endfunction

highlight default FakeClearTerm ctermfg=234 ctermbg=16 guifg=#333333 guibg=#000000
tnoremap <silent> <c-l> <c-\><c-n>:<c-u>call <sid>fake_clearterm()<cr>i
```

### Explanation:

The `FakeClearTerm` highlight group sets a dark gray foreground and black background which dims the text.  You would have to adjust this to match your color scheme.

`s:fake_clearterm()` gets the terminal window's top and bottom lines (`w0` and `w$` respectively).  Then it creates a pattern matching any line within window and applies the `FakeClearTerm` highlight group to it. The match is given a priority of `0` which allows searches to highlight text within the dimmed text.  The match ID `1234` is arbitrary.

`ctrl-l` is used to "clear" the text.  It's using `tnoremap` which means it has to be used in the terminal's insert mode.  In normal mode `ctrl-l` redraws the screen.

After "clearing", new text below the matched region will use default colors.

### Caveats:

- Neovim's highlighting won't overrule colors set by terminal's output.  Since `picocom` doesn't print colors, this shouldn't be a big deal.
- Scrolling up is still possible and the text in the scrollback won't be dimmed.
- You have to `:call matchdelete(1234)` yourself to remove the highlight.